# Solve $ord_x(2) = 20$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

Given that the (multiplicative) order of $2$ mod $x$ is $20$, how can I work out what $x$ is?

Comment: $2^{20}-1=3\times 5^2\times11\times 31\times 41$.  Any $x$ you can build out of those terms will work.  For other exponents, the problem is as hard as the factoring.

Comment: $x=2^{20} - 1$ is an obvious answer, but not necessarily complete...

Comment: Actually, you should clarify your question.  The header simply requires that $2^{20}\equiv 1 \pmod x$ but the body of the text suggests that you want $20$ to be the order of $2\pmod x$.  These are related but different questions.

Comment: You conflate $2^{20}\equiv 1 \bmod x$ with the order of $2$ being $20$, but it only implies that the order of $2$ divides $20$.  As @lulu notes, your Question amounts to finding divisors $x$ of $2^{20}-1$ or more generally of $2^\alpha-1$.  These are easier than average factoring problems.

Comment: @hardmath What I actually wanted to do is $n$ such that the order of $2$ mod $n$ is $20$... how could I do this?

Comment: There are plenty solutions. Do you want all, or only one ?

Comment: @Peter I only want one. I would like to know how this is found also, so the simplest one would do. I also want to be able to be able to use this method to find for example $2^{10} \equiv 1$ mod $n$ and $2^{45} \equiv 1$ mod $n$.. so it would be great to know a workable method

Comment: Note:  the OP has edited the question to make the intent clear.  As it now stands, I do not believe there is any reason to close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We seek $x$ such that $2$ has order $20\pmod x$.  To do that, we first address the congruence $$2^{20}\equiv 1\pmod x$$

As $2^{20}-1=3\times 5^2\times 11\times 31\times 41$ we see that we are looking for $x$ that can be assembled from those terms.  we then have to eliminate the orders $2,4,5,10$ (aka the non-trivial divisors of $20$).   Clearly we need $x>20$

The smallest candidate is $x=25$.  We easily verify that $2^{10}-1=1023\equiv 23\pmod {25}$ (the smaller exponents can be ruled out by inspection).  Thus the order of $2\pmod {25}$ is $20$ as desired.

If you want a prime example, then $x=41$ works (it's the only one).  Brute force reveals that $2^{10}-1\equiv 39 \pmod {41}$ and again the smaller candidates can be ruled out by inspection.  That suffices.

The case of general exponent can be solved similarly...as you can imagine, it becomes difficult if $a$ is large.

Comment: We also need to rule out the divisors of $2^4-1=3\cdot 5$

Comment: @Peter  Absolutely.  Though, like I said, the candidates less than $10$ are easily handled by inspection.

Comment: Why $x=11\lt 25$ is not a solution?

Comment: I can answer myself now: because $x=11$ is a correct answer to the question before it was changed (it was $2^{20}\equiv 1\pmod x$)

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:-**

From [Euler Totient Function(or theorem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) we know-

> $$a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod n$$ for $\gcd(a,n)=1$

Here you have,$2^{20}\equiv1\pmod n$.

Comparing the two equations we have,$\phi(n)=20$.Try to find $n$ from it.

**Method 2:-**

We know that for all $n$,$(a-b)|(a^n-b^n)$ and $a^n-b^n$ is also divisible by $a+b$ if $n$ is odd.

So,We need to find $x$ such that $x|2^{20}-1$

Note that $2^{20}-1$ can be written as $2^{20}-1^{20}$.

This can be written in the following forms-

> $(2^5)^4-(1^5)^4$   Hence,$n=2^5-1$ is a factor.
>
> $(2^{10})^2-(1^{10})^2$  Hence,$n=2^{10}-1$ is a factor.
>
> $(2^4)^5-(1^4)^5$ Hence,both $2^4-1$ and $2^4+1$ are factors.

**Important note**-Factors of the values of $n$ given are also factors of the number.

Comment: These are not all the answers.  $2^{20}\equiv 1 \pmod {41}$ for example, but $\varphi(41)=40$.

Comment: You should say $\phi (n)=20$

Comment: Also:  $\varphi(50)=20$ but $50$ does not divide $2^{20}-1$.

Comment: ok thanks so need to find $n$ such that $\phi(n)=21$ .. $21 \neq p-1$. Let $n=p^s \implies 21= p^s-p^{s-1}$. Powers of primes $p$: $4, 9, 25, 49$. Let $n=25 \implies \phi(5^2)=5^2-5=20$... so $n=25$?

Comment: You should add a requirement that $n$ (or $x$ in the OP) is odd.

Comment: This post is extremely misleading.  with $n=41$, $2$ actually has order $20$ so $41$ solves even the stronger of the OP's possible questions but your method omits it.   If we are only after the congruence, not the actual order, then your method also  omits $3,5,11,31,\cdots$ just to mention the primes.

Comment: @lulu would this method suffice if we require just one possible $x$?

Comment: Can someone verify if $n=25$ works as I calculated?

Comment: @thinker Sure, but in that case it is overkill.  $x=3$ is obviously a solution.  And if you just factor $2^{20}-1=(2^{10}-1)(2^{10}+1)=(2^5-1)(2^5+1)(2^{10}+1)$ you see that $31=2^5-1$ is another solution.

Comment: @thinker  Of course $25$ is a solution.  In my first comment (above) I pointed out that anything you can assemble from the factoring $3\times5^2\times11\times31\times 41$ is a solution.  So $x=25$ works, as does $x=11\times31\times 41=13981$, among several options.

Comment: @thinker  Ah, you've edited your question.  If you actually want to show that the order is $20$ you have to work harder.  $25$ does work, but you have to check it.  I'll post something.

Comment: @lulu thank you so much, I was worried people would close my question before I got an answer

Comment: @lulu Edited my answer...check it out...

Comment: @thinker Edited my answer...check it out...

Answer (score 1):

By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem#Generalizations) we know that, in general, $n^{\varphi (x)} \equiv 1 \pmod x$ for every $n$ coprime with $x$. We want $x$, then, such that $\gcd (2,x) = 1$ (i.e. $2 \nmid x$) and $\varphi (x) =  20$.

By [Euler's product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function#Proof_of_Euler.27s_product_formula), $x = p_1 ^{n_1} \dots p_k ^{n_k}$, then $\varphi (x) = (p_1 - 1) p_1 ^{n_1 - 1} \dots (p_k - 1) p_k ^{n_k - 1}$. Since $\varphi (x) = 20 = (5-1) \cdot 5^1$, it follows that $k=1$ and $p_1 = 5$, so $x = 5^2 = 25$ is a solution (clearly $2 \nmid 25$).

Answer (score 0):

You need $$2^k\cdot2^{20-k}=1$$ for $k=1,2,...,20$. In other words $2^k$ has as inverse $2^{20-k}$ Since $2$ is a primitive root modulo $11$ we examine if this is verified for $x=11$. We have in the field $\mathbb F_{11}$ $$\begin{cases}2^1=2\\2^2=4\\2^3=8\\2^4=5\\2^5=10\\2^6=9\\2^7=7\\2^8=3\\2^9=6\\2^{10}=1\end{cases}$$ and we can see the condition $2^k\cdot2^{20-k}=1$ is verified. So $\color{red}{x=11}$

Is there another solution? I will come back (some trouble to write in English and I could less the first answer as many times).

NOTE.-This is an answer to the question as it was formulated before it was changed: this question was $2^{20}\equiv 1\pmod x$

Comment: To me it is not trivial that $2$ is a primitive root modulo $11$ - can you explain this further?

Comment: The fact that $\{2^1,2^2,2^3,....,2^{10}\}=\mathbb F_{11}\setminus \{0\}$ is a proof.

Answer (score 0):

The divisors of $2^{20}-1$, which are not also divisors of $2^{10}-1$ or $2^4-1$ do the job. You will quickly find out that the smallest number satisfying this is $25$.

You can determine them with PARI/GP :

```
? for(s=1,n,if((Mod(2^20-1,s)==0)*(Mod(2^10-1,s)<>0)*(Mod(2^4-1,s)<>0),print1(s,
" ")))
25 41 55 75 123 155 165 205 275 451 465 615 775 825 1025 1271 1353 1705  2255 232
5 3075 3813 5115 6355 6765 8525 11275 13981 19065 25575 31775 33825 41943 69905
95325 209715 349525 1048575
```